# Que signifie "le Barbarie" ?

Tags: sens, littérature, musique

Bonjour,

> Tout d'un coup une musique éclate, les durs flonflons, **le
> Barbarie**, ça monte de la rue.

Savez-vous ce que signifie "le Barbarie" ici ? Est-ce une référence péjorative au canard de Barbarie ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainement l'[orgue de Barbarie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgue_de_Barbarie).

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 1):

En vérifiant le texte de *Guignol's band*, on trouve un peu plus loin (page 650 dans mon édition) le passage suivant.

> Elle voulait que Virginie se relève, qu'elle se remette debout un petit
> peu, que c'était assez d'être allongée... qu'elle joue au piano...
> « C'est plus joli que le Barbarie ! ça gagne moins d'argent par
> exemple !

Il est évident que ce qui est plus joli, ce n'est pas le piano mais la musique du piano ; le mot « piano » est utilisé métonymiquement pour « musique du piano », [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/piano), mais pas dans cette phrase de Céline. Néanmoins, même si la musique du piano n'est pas nommée et que le représentatif réfère à quelque chose qui n'est pas dans le texte, on doit concevoir que  « c' » remplace « la musique du piano » ; si la musique du piano est plus jolie que le Barbarie, « le Barbarie » est utilisé métonymiquement pour « la musique de l'orgue de Barbarie ».

- Tout d'un coup une musique éclate, les durs flonflons, le Barbarie, ça monte de la rue.

Il n'y a presque pas de doute que « le Barbarie » est déjà utilisé métonymiquement  pour « la musique de l'orgue de Barbarie », ceci étant d'autant plus vrai que les flonflons est un manifestation musicale, pas vraiment de la musique mais bien des sons musicaux («  Accords, généralement bruyants, d'une musique d'harmonie, entendue à distance. », [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/flonflon)).